# WPF custom control doesn't bind

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, bind

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Menupedia.MiniRestaurantViewer"
x:Name="UserControl" Width="80" Height="100">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Label x:Name="label_Name" Content="{Binding _name, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="80" FontFamily="Public Enemy NF" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="#FFEF7B54" Margin="0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <Image x:Name="image_Logo" Source="{Binding _logo, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFF15A28" BorderThickness="1" Height="80" CornerRadius="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MiniRestaurantViewer : UserControl
{
    public int _id {get{return id;}}
    public string _name {get{return name;}}
    public ImageSource _logo {get{return logo;}}

    public MiniRestaurantViewer(int id, string name,byte[] logo)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.logo = ByteArrayToImageSource(logo);
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int id;
    private string name;
    private ImageSource logo;

    private ImageSource ByteArrayToImageSource(byte[] data)
    {
        BitmapImage image = null;
        if (null != data)
        {
            image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
            image.EndInit();
        }
        return image;
    }

    public MiniRestaurantViewer()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

that is my custom control. i want to do this

```
ListBox.Items.Add(new MiniRestaurantViewer(1,"test",null));
```

when i do it i see the UI element but it's empty (binding didn't work). Through the watch though i find that the public properties has values.. i don't know how to make it work and i have been tryin since 3 days please help me. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `DataContext to itself` if properties lies in code behind.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Menupedia.MiniRestaurantViewer"
             x:Name="UserControl" Width="80" Height="100"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this `this.DataContext = this;`  to make your code works  but you are far far away from  the best  practice of wpf which means using MVVM  try to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/03/13/understanding_2d00_the_2d00_basics_2d00_of_2d00_mvvm_2d00_design_2d00_pattern.aspx) first  as it can be a good start for a begineer

```
 public MiniRestaurantViewer(int id, string name,byte[] logo)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.logo = ByteArrayToImageSource(logo);
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot i know im far away from good code. but im new to wpf and i have a project due next monday and i have to make it work i chose to use wpf rather than windows forms so im kinda learning all together with developing this program. ill read ur link

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you need to use two way bindings to be able to make changes both way - from your view to model and from model to view. I did not see in your control Listbox, so probably it's from your mainWindow. In this case your have two oportunities - or to set datacontext of the mainWindow, like in an answers below, or set ListBox.Datacontext. Hope this will help you.